# Global variables and frame stack

Tags: c

The below program will read a positive integer from keyboard and print the binary equivalent. This program is using only one variable.

If global variables are not stored in frame stack, how this is working.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int n;
void binary(n)
{
    if(n>0)
    {
        binary(n/2);
        printf("%d",n%2);
    }
}

void main()
{
    scanf("%d",&n);
    binary(n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The program is actually using two variables. There is a global variable `n`, which is used by `main()`. There is a local variable, confusingly also named `n`, which is used by `binary()` and allocated on the stack.

---

Here are some excerpts from the code generated on my machine:

```
_binary:
...
        movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
        cmpl    $0, -4(%rbp)
...

_main:
...
        movq    _n@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rsi
        movl    (%rsi), %edi
        movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)          ## 4-byte Spill
        callq   _binary
...
        .comm   _n,4,2                  ## @n
```

The first excerpt contains part of the code generated for `binary()`. The parameter `n` is passed in the register `edi`, and is then stored on the stack. The following command compares it to zero, implementing part of `n>0`.

The second excerpt contains part of the code generated for `main()`. The global variable `n` is allocated as a [common symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501105/what-does-comm-mean). The excerpt consists of the function call `binary(n)`. You can see that `n` is pulled out of the global storage and put into `edi`, before calling `binary()`.